# Check browser console messages and response status codes in Playwright and Jest

Tags: jestjs, playwright

I recently started writing end to end tests using Playwright and Jest packages.

In a test I would like to check that, after loading a page, the browser console doesn't contain any error message and all the requests performed in background have the status code equal to 200 (or maybe at least different from 5XX).
The question is: what is the cleanest way to reach that?

Is the following a valid solution?

```
page.on('response', response => {
  expect(response.status()).toBe(200);
});
page.on('console', message => {
  expect(message.type()).not.toBe('error');
});
const response = await page.goto('https://url');
```

I don't know exactly why, but I thing I'm missing something.

Comment: That's a good approach. The problem is that the test will end as soon as `goto` finishes. So you might miss some errors.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes it's a valid solution.

*Now, to enrich my answer, some more content follows...*

I just wrote a class for gathering my API responses as a testing utility:

```js
import { Page } from 'playwright';

interface ApiStat {
  status: number,
  pathname: string
}

export class AssertApiCalls {
  private _apiStats: ApiStat[] = [];
  private readonly MY_FANCY_API_ADDRESS = 'http://localhost:4321';
  private readonly API_PATH = '/api/';

  constructor(page: Page) {
    this.initEventListener(page);
  }

  private initEventListener(page: Page) {
    page.on('response', response => {
      const url = new URL(response.url());
      const origin = url.origin;
      const pathname = url.pathname;
      const isApiPath = pathname.slice(0,5) === this.API_PATH;

      if (origin === this.MY_FANCY_API_ADDRESS && isApiPath) {
        this.pushStat({
          pathname: url.pathname,
          status: response.status()
        });
      }
    });
  }

  private pushStat(apiStat: ApiStat): void {
    this._apiStats.push(apiStat)
  }

  public routeWasCalledAtPositionWithStatus(
    pathname: string,
    position: number,
    status: number
  ): boolean {
    const apiCall = this._apiStats[position];
    return apiCall.pathname == pathname && apiCall.status === status;
  }

  get apiStats() {
    return this._apiStats;
  }
}
```

and with **jest** i now do things like

```js
...
expect(assertApiCalls.routeWasCalledAtPositionWithStatus('/api/user', 0, 401)).toBe(true);
expect(assertApiCalls.routeWasCalledAtPositionWithStatus('/api/user/refresh-jwt', 1, 200)).toBe(true);
expect(assertApiCalls.routeWasCalledAtPositionWithStatus('/api/user', 2, 200)).toBe(true);
...
```

of course, similar could happen with the console event listener.